# recaptcha design is messy, not accurate as shown on google

Tags: php, css, google-api, captcha

I am using recaptcha with PHP here:

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php

Have set it up for https url, I tried to fix the box using css but unable find any solutions, attached is the screen shot of it.

[image]

Any one else had this before ?

Comment: This is not going to answer your question, but personally I don't recommend reCAPTCHA... It's starting to get cracked by bots more and more, plus it's really **not user friendly**. Consider using something more user-friendly like [PlayThru](http://areyouahuman.com/) for instance. I have it on all my websites and it works great. I find it to have a better conversion rate.

Comment: This problem forced me to replace it with a simple php